# Rails 4 - undefined local variable or method `fullcalendar_engine_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, calendar, routes, fullcalendar

In rails 4.1, I am using `fullcalendar_engine` gem for calendar events and also I am using `devise` gem for sessions. The issue is, once user's logged into their account calendar will not display. Before user's log in calendar will display.

After log in, it will show the below error

```
undefined local variable or method `fullcalendar_engine_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000006139498>:0x00000002c9a980>`
```

`mount FullcalendarEngine::Engine => "/fullcalendar_engine"` is in the `routes.rb`

`mount_path: "/fullcalendar_engine"` is in the `fullcalendar.yml`

`fullcalendar_engine/...` is the folder structure and it will not comes under `users/` folder

The output of `rake routes` is,

```
fullcalendar_engine        /fullcalendar_engine             FullcalendarEngine::Engine
root GET                   /                                welcome#index

Routes for FullcalendarEngine::Engine:
get_events_events GET    /events/get_events(.:format) fullcalendar_engine/events#get_events
   move_event POST   /events/:id/move(.:format)   fullcalendar_engine/events#move
 resize_event POST   /events/:id/resize(.:format) fullcalendar_engine/events#resize
       events GET    /events(.:format)            fullcalendar_engine/events#index
              POST   /events(.:format)            fullcalendar_engine/events#create
    new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#new
   edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)   fullcalendar_engine/events#edit
        event GET    /events/:id(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#show
              PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#update
              PUT    /events/:id(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#update
              DELETE /events/:id(.:format)        fullcalendar_engine/events#destroy
         root GET    /                            fullcalendar_engine/events#index
```

After signed in as a user, how to display the calendar?

Comment: Try restarting the server

Comment: Yes. I have already tried it.

Comment: So, what is the output regarding this line of the command `rake routes`?

Comment: I have added it in the question.